# HTTP Cache Validation

Tags: validation, http, caching

I read Http spec. but I have a doubt and I hope someone can help me.

When a cache receives a request and has a stored response that must be validated  (before being served to the received request), does the cache send the received request (adding the conditional header fields it needs for validation) to the next server OR does the cache generate a new request  (with conditional header fields it needs for validation) and send the generated request to the next server?

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is that the client would issue the request with the key headers, and the server would either respond with the content or a 304 to use whatever was in the local cache.

This behavior should be the same for upstream caches along the network path all the way to the source of truth.

Comment: Thank you Paul. My understanding of English is not perfect... so are you saying that the cache forwards the received messagge adding it header fields it needs for check validity of the stored response/responses?

Comment: Not really - the browser will formulate a request.  If there are variant or conditional headers noted by the server, the browser will add those headers to the request.  If you have an upstream cache, it will simply forward the request to the server (unless it has unequivocally met all conditions to return a cached value).

Answer (score 0):

*"When a cache receives a request..."*

Cache doesn't receive HTTP request. It is user-agent (browser) that check cache to see whether there is any cache entry matched for an HTTP request. Cache itself is just a bunch of data stored in disk/memory.

"Does the cache send the received request...OR does the cache generate a new request..."

Cache doesn't send HTTP request. It is user-agent (browser)'s job to send the request.

In summary, cache is just bytes of data, it doesn't know when and where HTTP request is sent. All cache validation logic (cache related HTTP headers) is implemented by user-agent.